# How to show the user's post image in my facebook app

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am creating a facebook app in which I need to show the users post on my app. Using this code I am getting the user's post.

```
function getusername(){ 
    FB.api('/me/posts', function(response) {
        var l=response.data.length;
        var post;
        for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
            post = response.data[i];
            ShowOfferAccord(post);
        }
    });
}
```

Using this I am displaying the content of the post

```
ShowOfferAccord=function(post){
    var mes= post.message;
    var capt = post.caption;
    var des = post.description;
    var ilink = post.link;
    var image = post.picture;
    $("#pagecap").text(capt);
    $("#pagemsg").text(mes); 
    $("#pagedes").text(des);
    $("#pagelink").text(ilink);
}
```

My HTML is:

```
<div id="pagemsg" style='display:block; position:relative; height:auto; text-align:left; font-size:15px; color:#000;'></div>                
<div id="pagecap" style='position:relative; height:auto; text-align:left; font-size:15px; color:#000;'></div>
<div id="pageimg" style='position:relative; height:auto; text-align:left; font-size:15px; color:#000;'></div>
<div id="pagedes" style='position:relative; height:auto; text-align:left; font-size:15px; color:#000;'></div>
<div id="pagelink"style='position:relative; height:auto; text-align:left; font-size:15px; color:#000;'></div>
```

This is working.

But for image I am getting the image url.  I dont know how to display the image. Can anyone tell me how to parse this url as a source to the image tag and how to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you are getting url of  image, you could simply put it as source for `<img>` tag :

```
$("#pageimg").append("<img src='" + image + "' />");
```